# Curious Ethernet cable type based on pinouts: 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8 match, pins 3 and 6 might be flipped?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I've got a grey ethernet cable that doesn't appear to be a straight-thru or a [crossover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable#Crossover_cable_pinouts), I'm curious of the termination type.

Using a [Monoprice network tester (Product #8129)](https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=8129) these wires/pins match on either side of cable: 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8.

The very-basic tester says wire/pin 3 and 6 don't match on either side so I suspect they're crossed/flipped.

Cable is from old ISP equipment and attached label shows the following info: 90-196-010  112508

[image: Tester & cable]

### EDIT/UPDATE:

I know this kept you up at night (*sarcasm*), but for completeness-sake I am posting after I cracked open the cable:

[image: Jacks]
[image: Jack shielding removed]
[image: Cable shielding]
[image: Wiring order]

It appears pin/wire 7+8 are swapped on either end of the cable, but it doesn't seem to matter since that appears to be the silver/bare wire that's twisted together. Other test I found [Monoprice/LAN-Quicker-009](https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=8130) advised open & short; makes sense since wire/pin 3 & 6 aren't connected at all & 7 & 8 are connected together. Case closed, thanks internet peoples for solving another mystery!

Comment: Did you look at the wire colours in the plugs?  This will tell you if they're flipped.  It could also just be a bad cable.

Comment: @Jason if the pins are actually flipped then I don't think a bad cable could be the problem. Shorted pins, yes, but not flipped. That would indicate the ends were simply terminated incorrectly.

Comment: So what is the question? Whether the pins are flipped on the wiring? Or do you want to identify the cable?

Comment: In the question, he says, "I'm curious of the termination type." I think he was just interested how it was wired and, due to the limitations of his tester, wasn't able to immediately answer that question himself. I think the short answer is, "a) Pins 3 and 6 are crossed over (visually inspect to verify) and b) Buy a better continuity tester that's able to confirm it!"

Comment: It's not an ethernet cable and the cable tester isn't for RJ48C.

Comment: @wrecclesham Maybe you should wait for the original poster to clarify instead of defensively assuming intent.

Comment: @JakeGould why or? why not and? the questoner would not complain if given both

Comment: @barlop My thinking is if the original poster knew what the cable was, then there would be a deeper question here. Thus my strong belief that they don’t even know what the cable is; why then ask about termination without deep context?

Comment: @JakeGould sure, so answering what the cable is is clearly a good idea and is a pretty important key to the answer 'cos then you can say that a blah cable has or can have these two swapped.

Comment: @Jason the RJ45 ends are mostly metal so I can barely tell the colors let, taking a picture didn't help. -JakeGould I want to identify the cable but I thought that depended on it was terminated, bad wording. 
-wrecclesham yes curious of wiring. 
-barlop I agree more info is better than less info, once again badly worded

Comment: Thank you all for being so passionate & answering quickly, sometimes you do have to assume :). Getting another tester so I'll try to update with that info & I just may cut cable to see whats inside since I WAS going to use as regular patch cable, but obviously can't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Looks like it’s a 10 foot RJ48C TO RJ48C cable used for DSX-1 (T1) purposes.

I did a [Google search on the part number 90-196-010](https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&ei=Au2LXcO1L67t5gLflIPwDg&q=90-196-010%20&oq=90-196-010%20&gs_l=psy-ab.3...6281.6281..6703...0.0..0.113.113.0j1......0....1..gws-wiz.GFdlSbQ89-k&ved=0ahUKEwjDvv7Jhe3kAhWutlkKHV_KAO4Q4dUDCAo&uact=5) and it [lead me to this page](https://www.walkerfirst.com/item-details/?inv_id=90-196-010), which is clearly empty, but this info exists in [the Google cached content for that page](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:nvtQCBn5lkQJ:www.walkerfirst.com/item-details/%3Finv_id%3D90-196-010%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us):

- **Description**: CABLE_RJ48C TO RJ48C 10 FT STANDARD COLOR PAIRS
- **Manufacturer**: MNM

Looking up what an RJ48C cable is used for [leads me to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_jack) which [identifies the connector as 8P4C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_connector#8P8C) which describes it as:

> The 8 position 8 contact (8P8C) connector is a modular connector commonly used to terminate twisted pair and multi-conductor flat cable. These connectors are commonly used for Ethernet over twisted pair, registered jacks and other telephone applications, RS-232 serial communication using the EIA/TIA-561 and Yost standards, and other applications involving unshielded twisted pair, shielded twisted pair, and multi-conductor flat cable.

But in range context of RJ48C that [is described as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_jack) a “For four-wire data line (DSX-1)” and is described broadly as follows:

> A registered jack (RJ) is a standardized telecommunication network interface for connecting voice and data equipment to a service provided by a local exchange carrier or long distance carrier.

That said, if the cable is for DSX-1 purposes [that is defined as](https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/42061/dsx-1):

> (Digital Signal Cross-connect Level 1) A standard that defines the voltage, pulse width and plug and socket for connecting DS-1 (T1) signals.

So you have yourself a T1 cable used for connecting voice and data equipment to a service provided by a local exchange carrier or long distance carrier.

Comment: It was near some ISDN, PRI, & T1 old (adtran) equipment so that makes sense lol

Answer (score -2):

That particular tester cannot differentiate between different reasons for continuity failures.

[image]

I understand your confusion now.

We don't know if pins 3 and 6 are:

- shorted
- crossed
- disconnected

**Update:**

This looks like the internal wiring of an RJ45C cable:

[image]

It's interesting that there is continuity on pins 7 and 8, when everything I can find suggests that those two pins are "reserved for future use". I would have assumed that pins reserved for future use might not be physically connected but, according to the OP's tester, they are!

Even though it seems that we know what the cable is now, thanks to the other answer, it would still be very interesting to see the results from a continuity tester that's able to identify crossed pins, to see exactly what's going on inside this cable.

Comment: The OP is asking what type of cable he has, not why his tester cannot identify the cable. While your answer is interesting, it's not answering the question.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator The fact that the OP is using a tester at all tells you that he's primarily interested in *how it's wired.* From the title: "...pins 3 and 6 might be flipped?" From the question itself: "The very-basic tester says wire/pin 3 and 6 don't match on either side so I suspect they're crossed/flipped." I'm sure he's *also* interested to know what the purpose of the cable is, but fundamentally, he seems to want to know whether or not the pins are crossed, as this is a blindspot of his tester.

Comment: @wrecclesham “The fact that the OP is using a tester at all tells you that he's primarily interested in *how it's wired*.” A tester is often used to identify what a cable is or why it doesn’t work ask expected. I personally don’t care about wiring unless something just doesn’t work in a cable. My guess is the original poster simply wants to identify the cable and stated “termination type” as a way of stating as much.

Comment: I'm going to give you the benefit of the doubt that the OP has not been clear about his question. I've voted to close it as unclear so that he knows it needs clarification.